Add annotation on all methods of the classes present in a given directory
I have a usecase that I have created one annotation for our clients to onboard to our platform. These annotations when present over method intercept the method call and avoid making the production call and redirect the call to the dev environment.
Now we ask our clients to add this annotation in their code packages over different methods so that for customized usecases we can redirect the call to the dev stage with the help of these annotations present over these methods but clients generally forget adding this annotation in their code packages.
So is there any way in which we can provide some code to the clients which when added by the clients in their code pacakges, it automatially adds the annotation to all the methods of the classes present under a given directory during the compication process/runtime?
Or some other mechanis, we can avoid the code making the production call?
Thanks
Tried intercepting at different level but did not work

Run the same code in all environments, just with different configuration.  For example, the connection/credentials for dev is different from test, and is also different from prod.

Welcome to SO. Please learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example. Thank you.

I suggest you to use aspects. You can add behavior to all method in some package.
Here is example.

I am not sure if this answers the question, because the question is so ambiguous. But if you think that my answer to the other question really does answer this question, it would be better to vote to close the question as a duplicate instead of writing an answer consisting only of a link.

It isn't total duplicate. Problem can have several solutions. This one is only one of them.

I have no clear idea what exactly is the problem here. Either you understand this fuzzy problem description much better than I do, or you just decided to make an educated guess.

Question is "is there any way in which we can provide some code to the clients which when added by the clients in their code pacakges, it automatially adds the annotation to all the methods of the classes present under a given directory during the compication process/runtime?". It is pretty clear for me. If you have any questions about it you can request clarification in comments.

The code does not "add an annotation". I happen to be the AspectJ maintainer and kind of know what I am talking about. The question is just unclear,  which was my whole point.

I see it now. Question can be improved, but it is not that difficult to understand what is the intent.
